# Mapping JSON data to response object using AlamofireObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, alamofire

I am using [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) for mapping JSON response to response objects.
In my application i have JSON response like follow:

```
 { "HasError": false, "ErrorMessage": "", "SuccessMessage": "Login success", "data": { <Dict> } }
```

Here Dict can be any response object. How can i create mappable response object ?

My assumption is something like this:

```
class ResponseModel: BaseModel {
  var hasError: Bool?
  var errorMessage: String?
  var successMessage: String?
  var data: ResponseData?

  required init?(_ map: Map) {
    super.init(map)
  }

  override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map)

    hasError <- map["HasError"]
    errorMessage <- map["ErrorMessage"]
    successMessage <- map["SuccessMessage"]
    data <- map["data"]
  }
}
```

Where ResponseData is:

```
class ResponseData<T: Mappable>: Mappable {
  var responseData: T?

  required init?(_ map: Map){
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {
    responseData <- map["data"]
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `data` dict contain in the response?

Comment: It contains json data which will be different based on the api call